# WebSockets not working when application is built

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket

I have got to ASP.NET-Core 2.0 apps communicating via WebSockets.

App A is Server.
Application A is running on a remote server with Ubuntu.

App B is Client
Application B is running on a PC setup in my office.

When I test my applications locally in Debug everything works fine. Client connects to the server and they can exchange information.

However, when I build my Server app, Client can connect to it but when server tries to send a message to the client the message is not received by the client.

```
public async Task<RecievedResult> RecieveAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        RecievedResult endResult;
        var buffer = new byte[Connection.ReceiveChunkSize];
        WebSocketReceiveResult result;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        do
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                throw new TaskCanceledException();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Server Invoke");
            // result never finishes when application is build. On debug it finishes and method returns the correct result
            result = await _webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), cancellationToken);

            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                await CloseAsync(cancellationToken);
                endResult = new RecievedResult(null, true);
                return endResult;
            }
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, result.Count);
        } while (!result.EndOfMessage);
        endResult = new RecievedResult(memoryStream, false);
        return endResult;
    }
```

This is the part of code where everything hangs. 
What I tried was:

```
Build Server - Build Client => not working 
Build Server - Debug Client => not working 
Debug Server - Debug Client => working
```

I need any advice what might be wrong here and where I should look for issues.
Console if free of errors. Everything hangs on:

```
 result = await _webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), cancellationToken);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your client and server are in different networks. Are you 100% sure that they can see them?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am sure they see each other. I have got few Console.WriteLines during establishing connection and all of them are fine. I didn't mention that I use Nginx proxy on the server that holds the Server app. But without this proxy, the connection couldn't be established.

Comment: I also checked if this can be caused by using Nginx as a proxy, but disabling it and running projects on the same machine did not help

Comment: I succeded to resolve the issue by publishing Server Application with "Debug" configuration but I have to idea why it works this way...

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a solution. Weird, really weird. I'm wondering what are the exact differences in the code "debug" vs "release". I found only some info about optimalization: removing unused vars, unused loops and so on. But I do not see any of them in your code. I'm sorry that I cant help you, if you ever found the solution, please, describe it here, maybe someone else has such weird problems too.

Comment: The thing that breaks the Server app is "Optimize code" option checked in application Properties Build settings. Disabling it for Release configuration makes it work again but I don't know why :(

Comment: Yep, because "Optimize code" is what differ "Release" vs "Debug" (I'm not sure if ONLY, but it does). Maybe some good idea will be to compare IL from "Debug" and "Release" and look for the difference?

Comment: This is what I did yesterday. When our server sends a message to the client, in fact, it invokes clients methods using stack trace analysis and Reflection. There seem to be differences while analyzing code that is Optimized and NOT, and that's what documentation says [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-optimized-code?view=vs-2017). However we didn't notice any significant changes while analyzing optimized dll with [link](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy), in fact, the code worked perfectly while debugging optimized code...